# How to print out parts of columns in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I am relatively new to Pandas. I need help with splitting certain sections of columns and organizing them into different sections (countries sorted into regions). I tried some methods I thought of and it did not work, here is the code I started from.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('countries.csv')

countrieslist = {
    'Asia': list(df.columns.values),
    'Europe': list(df.columns.values),
    'Others': list(df.columns.values)
}

print(f"Countries in Asia - {countrieslist['Asia']}")
print(f"Countries in Europe - {countrieslist['Europe']}")
print(f"Countries in Others - {countrieslist['Others']}")
```

I tried outputting the code above, and the output result is

```
Countries in Asia - ['   ', ' Brunei Darussalam ', ' Indonesia ', ' Malaysia ', ' Philippines ', ' Thailand ', ' Viet Nam ', ' Myanmar ', ' Japan ', ' Hong Kong ', ' China ', ' Taiwan ', ' Korea, Republic Of ', ' India ', ' Pakistan ', ' Sri Lanka ', ' Saudi Arabia ', ' Kuwait ', ' UAE ', ' United Kingdom ', ' Germany ', ' France ', ' Italy ', ' Netherlands ', ' Greece ', ' Belgium & Luxembourg ', ' Switzerland ', ' Austria ', ' Scandinavia ', ' CIS & Eastern Europe ', ' USA ', ' Canada ', ' Australia ', ' New Zealand ', ' Africa ']
```

What the output should be:

```
Countries in Asia - ' Brunei Darussalam ', ' Indonesia ', ' Malaysia ', ' 
Philippines ', ' Thailand ', ' Viet Nam ', ' Myanmar ', ' Japan ', ' Hong Kong ', ' 
China ', ' Taiwan ', ' Korea, Republic Of ', ' India ', ' Pakistan ', ' Sri Lanka ', ' 
Saudi Arabia ', ' Kuwait ', ' UAE '
Countries in Europe - ' United Kingdom ', ' Germany ', ' France ', ' Italy ', ' 
Netherlands ', ' Greece ', ' Belgium & Luxembourg ', ' Switzerland ', ' Austria ', ' 
Scandinavia ', ' CIS & Eastern Europe '
Countries in Others – ' USA ', ' Canada ', ' Australia ', ' New Zealand ', ' Africa '
```

More info: this is the output of `print(df.columns)`:

[image]

Comment: You have the same values in all the keys in the dictionary. I'm guessing you need different column for every key?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to output different columns for every key

Comment: Use `df['column_name']`

Comment: what is the content of countries.csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume if you run `df.columns`, you will get an array like this:

```
['   ', ' Brunei Darussalam ', ' Indonesia ', ' Malaysia ', ' Philippines ', ' Thailand ', ' Viet Nam ', ' Myanmar ', ' Japan ', ' Hong Kong ', ' China ', ' Taiwan ', ' Korea, Republic Of ', ' India ', ' Pakistan ', ' Sri Lanka ', ' Saudi Arabia ', ' Kuwait ', ' UAE ', ' United Kingdom ', ' Germany ', ' France ', ' Italy ', ' Netherlands ', ' Greece ', ' Belgium & Luxembourg ', ' Switzerland ', ' Austria ', ' Scandinavia ', ' CIS & Eastern Europe ', ' USA ', ' Canada ', ' Australia ', ' New Zealand ', ' Africa ']
```

So your dictionary definition should be:

```
cols = [e.strip() for e in list(df.columns)]
countrieslist = {
    'Asia':   cols[ 1:19],
    'Europe': cols[19:30],
    'Others': cols[30:  ]
}
```

What I have here, `cols` is a list of country names, and I'm slicing it using each name's index in this format: `cols[start:end]`. Note that the start index is inclusive, whereas the end index is exclusive.

Alternatively you can skip the dictionary and print directly

```
print(  f"Countries in Asia - {cols[ 1:19]}")
print(f"Countries in Europe - {cols[19:30]}")
print(f"Countries in Others - {cols[30:  ]}")
```

Output:

```
Countries in Asia - ['Brunei Darussalam', 'Indonesia', 'Malaysia', 'Philippines', 'Thailand', 'Viet Nam', 'Myanmar', 'Japan', 'Hong Kong', 'China', 'Taiwan', 'Korea, Republic Of', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Sri Lanka', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Kuwait', 'UAE']
Countries in Europe - ['United Kingdom', 'Germany', 'France', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'Greece', 'Belgium & Luxembourg', 'Switzerland', 'Austria', 'Scandinavia', 'CIS & Eastern Europe']
Countries in Others - ['USA', 'Canada', 'Australia', 'New Zealand', 'Africa']
```

Comment: Hmm, when i run `df.columns` it prints out all the columns which are countries. What I am looking is if there is a function to take certain parts of the entire column and sort them into keys of the dictionary. I'm thinking of putting a function in the dictionary to sort (taking select columns from the whole column and putting it in a specific key) and the print function is to output the value (list) of a specific key

Comment: can you display the `df.columns` output in the question? Or better, share `countries.csv` from Google Drive or from somewhere

Comment: The output is too long so i decided to put this in a image. https://imgur.com/a/7POi99j
I used print(df.columns) to output what it is shown in the image.